# wp_redirect is not working sometimes

Tags: wp-redirect

I've tested the following code in my `function.php`:

```
if ( $_GET['test'] ) {
  wp_redirect('https://google.com');
}
```

and it works, if I go to `https://example.com/?test=true`, I will be redirected to Google.

But I found out when I put `wp_redirect()` in a function hooked to some action, it won't work. Instead after its execution users will stay on the same page, and, in my case, some CSS files seems not being loaded.

Since I haven't figured out what kind of actions will trigger this behavior, it is hard for me to reproduce the problem and demonstrate it in a simple way. So I take some screen recording, hope that will help make sense of the problem I am experiencing:
https://www.loom.com/share/4cfad90fde494fbd99db113c30b7555b

Comment: From what I could tell, the problem is because `wp_redirect()` (which uses the native [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function in PHP) should actually be called on page load, or before any output is sent (to the browser), but then you actually called the function after the submit button is (and other output are) rendered...

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) say:

> Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost
> always be followed by a call to exit;:

```
wp_redirect( $url );
exit;
```

Comment: Did you watch my video? I did have `exit` in the code

Comment: You should put the exit in your code in the question then to avoid confusion. Or post the code you're having the problem with instead.

Comment: Firstly, it shouldn't be necessary to watch a video - you could have easily included the problematic code in your question. Secondly, though you do indeed include `exit` in your code, you do not include it in the right place. `if (wp_redirect('https://google.com')) exit;` means exit if the redirect was successful, which it wasn't because you didn't exit after it.